# Difference between thunderbird and firefox add-ons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, thunderbird-addon

I created a simple Firefox addon with the [Add-on-SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/developers/builder) that changes a configvalue:
https://github.com/rubo77/devPixelsPerPx-Toggle

This addon works fine on Firefox, but I would like it to work for Thunderbird too.

What are the differences between an add-on for firefox and an add-on for Thunderbird?

Or do I have to use another SDK when I want to develop a Thunderbird add-on?